# Django optimize query update

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a function which opens a txt file (350k lines), reads each line and updates fields in the database. The database has around 250k-300k records.

It runs way too slow for me.

Could you help me with optimizing it the query or the way the import is being done?

Query:

```
PlaceGroupMatch.objects.filter(**query_kwargs).update(sym_ul=int(line[5]), updated=True, updated_date=datetime.now())
```

Whole code:

```
def street_postal_codes():
    output_file_name = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, "postal", "ulice_GUS.txt")
    with open(output_file_name, 'r+') as handle:
        next(handle)
        lines = csv.reader(handle, delimiter='\t')

    lines = list(lines)

    def update_data(lines):
        transaction.set_autocommit(False)
        for index, line in enumerate(lines):
            query_kwargs = {
                "sym_ext": int(line[10]),
                "sym_pod":int(line[4]),
                "updated": False
            }

            qs = PlaceGroupMatch.objects.filter(**query_kwargs).update(sym_ul=int(line[5]), updated=True, updated_date=datetime.now())
            print index
            if index % 5000 == 0:
                print index, datetime.now()
        transaction.commit()
        transaction.set_autocommit(True)

    update_data(lines)
```

Comment: I can only think of having combined index having fields sym_ext, sym_pod and updated fields to speedup query part.

Comment: I agree with @jtiai, but to be honest the problem is not really the speed of the query, it's the fact that you're doing it once for every line in the file.

Comment: Indexes helped a lot. I totally forgot about them this time.

Comment: I could also add a cache layer to skip queries for kwargs with sym_ext and sym_pod. This would avoid a lot of db hits.

Comment: I suggest deleting the line `lines=list(lines)`, which reads all 300k records into memory at once.  Leaving it as a generator from `csv.reader` will be a little more efficient -- data will stream from disk.